# How to get list of all available fonts in openpyxl or python-pptx?

Tags: python, fonts, openpyxl, python-pptx

I am trying to create a Combobox in Tkinter with a list of all the available fonts in Microsoft office. I am hoping either python-pptx or openpyxl libraries would have a list, but after reading the docs, I couldn't find the location. Where are the list of font name strings stored in either openpyxl or python-pptx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be possible using `python-pptx`:

```
>>> from pptx.text.fonts import FontFiles
>>> FontFiles._installed_fonts()
{('Agency FB', True, False): 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\AGENCYB.TTF', ...
```

As you can see in [its source code](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/pptx/text/fonts.py), this method returns "a dict mapping a font descriptor to its font file path". Also, you can checkout the `_iter_font_files_in` method of the same class to understand what is a "font descriptor":

> Each item is a key/value pair. The key is a (family_name, is_bold, is_italic) 3-tuple, like ('Arial', True, False), and the value is the absolute path to the font file.

So, `('Agency FB', True, False)` means: "the font in this path is named 'Agency FB', is bold and is not italic".

Comment: Thank you. I can generate a list using the `dict.keys()`